# Pack external files - with photoshop files?

Tags: materials, image, linked-data, packed-data

Ok I know you can pack external images into your blend by packing external data, but I this doesnt really work with photoshop files.

I have several images as planes that link back to .ai files that are placed into photoshop files, and these are fed into blender. Packing them results in gray images - what's the easiest way to pack files so I can send the blend to another computer?

Answer (score 1):

a bit late, but I think the best solution is to save those PSDs as TIFFs.
TIFF is apparently supported by Blender for Packing. And you can still place your .ai files in a TIFF file.

I am having the same issue right now, and all PSDs were't packed and appeared pink.
But all TIFFs are still there. So I think that should be a good workaround I think.