# why my texture is not appearing?

Tags: rendering

I made pikachu in Blender and pack everything in but after packing it . Now, suddenly my texture is not appearing of certain areas and appearing as purple , I am adding a image for your reference. Kindly help. Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are apparently using Photoshop PSD files directly as image textures.

While this this may work to a certain extent, packing is not supported. PSD files may be packed for transport while "in transit", but they can't be [used directly, or read from memory inside the blend](https://developer.blender.org/T70495) as stated in the bug report.

Possible workarounds are to unpack first, or [pack as layered tiff files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116028/pack-external-files-with-photoshop-files).

Comment: okay , thank you